# Grouping and Subtotals for total sales per agent, per day

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hi I asked today a similar question but i forgot to ask this one.

what i have to do is.But i didn't find out how to do it exactly.

"Make a table showing the total sales per agent, per day (data on the x-axis). View the report in the outline view and set the subtotals below the group. Repeat the number of agents within each group."

this is the table.

```
Datum Artikel Agent Kanaal  Sales
3.01.2015   1   1   1   45612
3.01.2015   2   2   1   12365
4.01.2015   1   2   1   12345
4.01.2015   1   2   2   45230
5.01.2015   2   1   2   45610
6.01.2015   2   1   1   74102
6.01.2015   1   2   1   12300
7.01.2015   1   1   2   12589
7.01.2015   2   2   1   45600
9.01.2015   2   1   2   45600
9.01.2015   1   2   2   65400
10.01.2015  2   1   2   54600
10.01.2015  1   2   1   56400
13.01.2015  2   1   2   74100
13.01.2015  1   2   2   14700
14.01.2015  1   1   2   32500
14.01.2015  1   2   1   65200
18.01.2015  2   2   2   36900
18.01.2015  2   1   1   25800
22.01.2015  2   1   1   14700
22.01.2015  1   1   2   41700
23.01.2015  1   2   2   52800
23.01.2015  1   1   1   63900
26.01.2015  1   2   2   35700
26.01.2015  2   2   1   15900
27.01.2015  1   1   1   97100
28.01.2015  1   2   1   31700
31.01.2015  1   1   1   93100
```

and this is what i've done.

```
Sum of Sales    Column Labels       
Row Labels  1   2   Grand Total
1           
3.01.2015   45612       45612
5.01.2015       45610   45610
6.01.2015   74102       74102
7.01.2015       12589   12589
9.01.2015       45600   45600
10.01.2015      54600   54600
13.01.2015      74100   74100
14.01.2015      32500   32500
18.01.2015  25800       25800
22.01.2015  14700   41700   56400
23.01.2015  63900       63900
27.01.2015  97100       97100
31.01.2015  93100       93100
1 Total 414314  306699  721013
2           
3.01.2015   12365       12365
4.01.2015   12345   45230   57575
6.01.2015   12300       12300
7.01.2015   45600       45600
9.01.2015       65400   65400
10.01.2015  56400       56400
13.01.2015      14700   14700
14.01.2015  65200       65200
18.01.2015      36900   36900
23.01.2015      52800   52800
26.01.2015  15900   35700   51600
28.01.2015  31700       31700
2 Total 251810  250730  502540
Grand Total 666124  557429  1223553
```

Comment: What is the Ouput you require? also learn the Pivot table tutorial first for basic understanding and try do it on your own.

Comment: I've already tried. But I am not sure, am i doing correctly or not. So the second table what i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to Grouping see the below links.
http://www.wikihow.com/Group-and-Outline-Excel-Data
[http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/..](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-HA010095247.aspx)

Below is the Screen Shot for Better understanding. Now you try to get the required output.

[image]